# Why are we adding X in this Bernoulli distribution question?

Tags: probability, statistics, random, binomial-distribution

An interviewer is given a list of people she can interview. If the interviewer needs
to interview 6 people, and if each person (independently) agrees to be interviewed
with probability 3/4, what is the probability that her list of people will enable her
to obtain her necessary number of interviews if the list consists of (a) 6 people and
(b) 10 people? For part (b), what is the probability that the interviewer will speak
to exactly (c) 7 people and (d) 9 people on the list?

For part (b), I thought I would use the Bernoulli Distribution and find out the value when X = 6 (since she wants 6 successes).

I would have P(X=6) and get some answer. However the answer is P(X>=6) = P(X=6) + P(X=7) + P(X=8) + P(X=9) + P(X=10)

Why are they getting the sum for all bigger than 6 and not just 6?

EDIT: for part c) I think I'm supposed to use a negative binomial but I'm stuck after that.

Comment: The necessary number of interviews is 6. The interviewer can choose 6 people to be interviewed provided that *at least* 6 people agree to be interviewed (if more agree, then she can reject them, I suppose). (By the way, this is the binomial distribution, not the Bernoulli distribution.)

Comment: This may be the wrong place to ask but what is the difference? I've been plugging in the same formula everywhere?

Comment: This has to do with the "common sense" background of the question.  It's assumed that "needs to interview 6 people" does not mean "needs to have exactly 6 people agree to interview".  There's an implicit assumption that the interviewer could decline additional candidates or interview them without failing the task at hand.

Comment: I suppose so. Thank you. I can see this direction of the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interviewer doesn't want 6 successes, she wants *at least* 6 successes. The key is:

> her to obtain her necessary number of interviews

If she has 7 interviews, that's fine. If she has 8 that's fine too, etc.

Comment: Where did you see that it was at least? I am confused because when she gets 6 people isn't she going to stop interviewing?

Comment: @qaispak Sure. For example if ALL people agree (or would agree) to an interview, did she not get the necessary number of interviews?

Comment: Okay. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the Bernoulli distribution: X~Bernoulli(10,3/4), P(X=6) gives the probability that EXACTLY 6 people accept to be interviewed. Since you want the probability of her obtaining at least 6 people, the answer is:

P(X>=6) = P(X=6) + P(X=7) + P(X=8) + P(X=9) + P(X=10), as stated.

Comment: Yes but I am not sure where the "at least" comes from the question.